# EWS error: Exceeded maximum count of 1000 items that can be deleted in a single request

Tags: c#, synchronization, exchangewebservices

i am using EWS Exchange Sync, and in one of my methods, it's saying that i exceeded maximum count of 1000 items that can be deleted in a single request. Can this be solved by instead of deleting everything from the calendar, we only delete from today and onwards, instead of deleting back in time?

The method responsible for the error is here:

```
        public void DeleteAllSafeAppointments(SCDriftConnection conn, ExchangeService service, SAFEAgent agent) {
        if(conn == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("conn");
        if(service == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("service");
        if(agent == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("agent");

        try {
            var calendar = GetAgentCalendar(service, agent);

            service.DeleteItems(GetAllSafeAppointments(calendar).Select(a => a.Id), DeleteMode.HardDelete, SendCancellationsMode.SendToNone, null);

            var scheduledActivitiesOnAgent = ScheduledActivity.GetScheduleToExchange(new QueryParameters<ScheduledActivity>(s => s.Initials == agent.Initials && s.ExchangeId != null));

            foreach(var schedAct in scheduledActivitiesOnAgent) {
                schedAct.ExchangeId = null;

                schedAct.Save(conn);
            }

            ResetAgentSyncState(calendar, agent);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            throw new Exception("An error occured while clearing exchange calendar for " + agent.Initials, ex);
        }

        agent.ExchangeSyncronizationSettings.LastSync = DateTime.Now;
        agent.ExchangeSyncronizationSettings.Save(conn);
    }
```

The full error message is here:

### > An error occured in Safe-Exchange Sync, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

Exceeded maximum count of 1000 items that can be deleted in a single request. 
   ved Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ProcessWebException(WebException webException)
   ved Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest request)
   ved Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ValidateAndEmitRequest(IEwsHttpWebRequest& request)
   ved Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
   ved Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.InternalDeleteItems(IEnumerable`1 itemIds, DeleteMode deleteMode, Nullable`1 sendCancellationsMode, Nullable`1 affectedTaskOccurrences, ServiceErrorHandling errorHandling, Boolean suppressReadReceipts)
   ved Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.DeleteItems(IEnumerable`1 itemIds, DeleteMode deleteMode, Nullable`1 sendCancellationsMode, Nullable`1 affectedTaskOccurrences)
   ved SafeToExchangeSync.SafeScheduleSyncronizer.DeleteAllSafeAppointments(SCDriftConnection conn, ExchangeService service, SAFEAgent agent)

Comment: What's wrong with just making multiple requests?

Comment: Nothing, but in this specific example i want to instead of deleting back in time ,i want to delete from today and onwards.

Comment: Why not make your question about that rather than this error? And in short, no it can't be resolved by deleting everything from today onwards: consider the situation where there are more than 1000 items from today onwards.

Comment: Well, i know there wont be more than 1000 items from today and onwards, please specify what should be done? Other than making multiple requests and therefore rewrite a lot.

Comment: Why not just loop batches of 1000 over the `Deleteitems` method? It doesn't seem like much of a rewrite ought to be needed.

Comment: The DeliteItems method is apart of the API not a self-written method, so it does seem kind of complicated, isn't there any easier solution?

Comment: I don't see why it seems complicated, it's pretty straight-forward. I've added an answer to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

You could just batch the request. I've written a generic batch method for this:

```
private IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Batch<T>(IEnumerable<T> input, int batchSize)
{
    List<T> items = new List<T>();
    foreach (var item in input)
    {
        items.Add(item);
        if (items.Count == batchSize)
        {
            yield return items;
            items = new List<T>();
        }
    }
    if (items.Count > 0)
    {
        yield return items;
    }
}
```

And you can now use it to split your items into batches:

```
var batches = Batch(GetAllSafeAppointments(calendar).Select(a => a.Id), 1000);
foreach (var batch in batches)
{
    service.DeleteItems(batch, DeleteMode.HardDelete, SendCancellationsMode.SendToNone, null);
}
```

Now a maximum of 1000 will be deleted at once.

Comment: Thank you, I am quite new to C# and using the EWS so I haven't thought of that. The generic batch method do i need to change any of the variables, or can i just implement the solution you proposed this exact way?

Comment: You can just use the Batch method as is - it takes generic T so it will automatically infer the type from what's passed into it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Exchange APIs, but I'm going to assume one of two things: 1) It's throttling because there are too many requests (how many items are you deleting?) or 2) Some of the IDs in the batch are already deleted (do you have duplicates)? - You might have to post a separate question about that though as I'm not able to help with that particular message.

Comment: Do you have another workaround perhaps other than doing this? Maybe using the Date to only delete items from today/forward in time?

Comment: @kwesi if the items returned by `GetAllSafeAppointments` includes the date, you could do something like `.Where(a => a.datefield >= DateTime.Now.Date).Select(a => a.Id))`

Comment: Hi john, it doesn't exactly include the date, but a folder object, look at code below:

Comment: Assuming it's the same [object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.appointment_properties(v=exchg.80).aspx), there seems to be `Start`, `End`, and `DateTimeCreated`.

Comment: Seems like the same object that you have found the documentation for, which is appointment. What do you suggest i should use Start, End and DateTimeCreated for? How do  i utilize that to only delete appointments today/in the future?

Answer (score 0):

```
private IEnumerable<Appointment> GetAllSafeAppointments(Folder calendar) {
            ItemView view = new ItemView(512);

            view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);

            SearchFilter filter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And,
                                                                          new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(SafeAppointmentFlag, true));

            while(true) {
                var results = SendExchangeRequest(() => calendar.FindItems(filter, view));

                foreach(var r in results.OfType<Appointment>())
                    yield return r;

                if(!results.MoreAvailable)
                    break;

                view.Offset = results.NextPageOffset.Value;
            }
        }
```