# EWS are not currently available for this request because none of the Client Access Servers in the destination site could process the reques

Tags: c#, synchronization, exchangewebservices

At first I received this error, when trying to delete all appointments on calendar on a specific person: "Exceeded maximum count of 1000 items that can be deleted in a single request"

Then i tried fixing that by using batches of max size 1000 using this code:

```
    private IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Batch<T>(IEnumerable<T> input, int batchSize)
{
    List<T> items = new List<T>();
    foreach (var item in input)
    {
        items.Add(item);
        if (items.Count == batchSize)
        {
            yield return items;
            items = new List<T>();
        }
    }
    if (items.Count > 0)
    {
        yield return items;
    }
}
```

and then using this:

```
    var batches = Batch(GetAllSafeAppointments(calendar).Select(a => a.Id), 1000);
foreach (var batch in batches)
{
    service.DeleteItems(batch, DeleteMode.HardDelete, SendCancellationsMode.SendToNone, null);
}
```

Then i receive this error:

> Exchange Web Services are not currently available for this request because none of the Client Access Servers in the destination site could process the request. ved Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ProcessWebException(WebException webException) ved Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest request) ved Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ValidateAndEmitRequest(IEwsHttpWebRequest& request) ved Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest1.Execute()
>      ved Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.InternalDeleteItems(IEnumerable1 itemIds, DeleteMode deleteMode, Nullable1 sendCancellationsMode, Nullable1 affectedTaskOccurrences, ServiceErrorHandling errorHandling, Boolean suppressReadReceipts) ved Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.DeleteItems(IEnumerable1 itemIds, DeleteMode deleteMode, Nullable1 sendCancellationsMode, Nullable`1 affectedTaskOccurrences) ved SafeToExchangeSync.SafeScheduleSyncronizer.DeleteAllSafeAppointments(SCDriftConnection conn, ExchangeService service, SAFEAgent agent) i S:\s0book\xxx\xxx\xxx\SafeToExchangeSync\SafeScheduleSyncronizer.cs:linje 151

Answer (score 4):

This error generally happens when you don't use X-AnchorMailbox header and your accessing a Mailbox other then the primary mailbox associated with the account. The easiest fix is just set the X-AnchorMailbox on the ExchangeService object to the Mailbox your trying to access eg

```
service.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", "Mailbox@domain.com");
```

You should always use this header regardless as it ensure that your request always get routed to the correct CAS servers.

Comment: So in this specific case, should i place this line of code before or after using the service.DeleteItems method?

Comment: Before so it will be sent when you execute the DeleteItems Method

Comment: But the problem is i don't have any Mailbox class used. So the "Mailboxname" isn't finding anything to reference to since i never declared or instantiated a Mailbox class, this is for deleting everybody's mailbox.

Comment: Your just setting the Header on the ExchangeService Class, MailboxName in the above example is just a string I've modified the sample you don't need to use the Mailbox Class. Your batch however should only contain deletes from one mailbox. You shouldn't be trying to span multiple mailbox within a submitted batch.

Comment: So in regards to the solution you originally proposed, instead of MailboxName what should i put in, how do i make sure my batch only contains the deletes from a single mailbox? I appreciate your help and guidance, as I am very new to EWS and C# but got assigned to this task.

Comment: You should use the primary smtp address of the mailbox where the content is located that your trying to delete. I don't know how your getting the items to delete but that's where you should be able to identify what the source mailbox was.

Comment: Is there any other solution to this specific problem? Other than batching which results in this exception to begin with? How to fix the very core of my problem which is stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49812301/ews-error-exceeded-maximum-count-of-1000-items-that-can-be-deleted-in-a-single

Comment: The problem is the way it's been architected to start with. Simplify the code by limiting execution context to one mailbox at a time

Comment: So instead of the List object in the Batch method, i use a Mailbox class?